# Найти индексы массива, которые в сумме дают число

Tags: java

Задание такое: Дан массив целых чисел. Необходимо реализовать метод, который
возвращает индексы массива, значения которых в сумме дают число
переданное в массив.
Предполагается, что массив содержит только уникальные числа и всегда
имеет искомые числа.
Один и тот же элемент не может быть использован дважды.
array = [3, 8, 15, 17], Number = 23
result = [1,2]

Я решил бы это через массив линейно, то есть искал бы значение равное разнице сначала 23- первый элемент и так далее, но как это сделать быстрее используя коллекции?

Comment: В сумме может быть любое количество элементов? Т.е. array = [3, 5, 8, 15, 30] для суммы 23 ответ [0, 1, 3] (числа 3, 5, 15) может быть?

Comment: Нет, только два

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подправить алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1365760/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)

Answer (score 0):

Возможен вот такой вариант решения задачи, достаточно простой и понятный.

```java
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    int index = 0;
    int index2 = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) { // "- 1" т.к. массив начинается с нуля.
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                index = i;
                index2 = j;
            }
        }
    }
    int[] list = {index, index2}; 
    return list;
    }
```

Если что то не понятно, напишите мне, постараюсь помочь.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]