# Подправить алгоритм

Tags: java, алгоритм

Задача: *Дан массив целых чисел, необходимо вернуть индексы двух чисел, сумма которых равна заданному числу. Можно считать, что массив будет иметь ровно одно решение. Нельзя использовать одно и то же число дважды*.

```
Пример1: [2, 7, 11, 15], 9
Ответ: [0, 1]

Пример2: [3, 2, 4], 6
Ответ: [1, 2]
```

Если считать, что массив упорядочен (в условии этого нет!), то решаю методом двух указателей:

```
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int l = 0, r = nums.length - 1;

        while (l < r) {
            int currentSum = nums[l] + nums[r];

            if (currentSum == target) {
                return new int[]{l, r};
            } else if (currentSum > target) {
                r--;
            } else if (currentSum < target) {
                l++;
            }
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("the pair is not found");
    }
```

Сложность **O(n)**.

Но тут проблема со вторым примером:

```
Пример2: [3, 2, 4], 6
Ответ: [1, 2]
```

Должен выдать 1,2 а у меня исключение вылетает.
**Подскажите, как подправить алгоритм для случая, когда массив неупорядоченный?**

Comment: А предварительно отсортировать?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за подсказку с **HashMap**! Вот итоговое правильное решение (система его приняла):

```
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            map.put(nums[i], i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            int key = target - nums[i];

            if (map.containsKey(key) && i != map.get(key)) {
                return new int[]{i, map.get(key)};
            }
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("the pair is not found");
    }
```

Comment: А зачем два раза проходить по массиву?

Comment: Первый проход по массиву: заполняем мапу. Второй проход: ищем нужные индексы.

Comment: Решение с одним проходом было предоставлено ещё 25 декабря, я так понимаю, собственное решение было написано ради галочки )

Answer (score 3):

Да никак не подправить. Или сортировать, или использовать другой алгоритм - в простейшем случае два цикла с квадратичным времени, либо использовать хэш-таблицу, тогда время линейное, но памяти O(n)

Answer (score 2):

Если сортировка не рассматривается как вариант, то наиболее простое решение без использования дополнительных структур данных, проверка во вложенных циклах:

```java
public static int[] twoSum(final int target, int ... nums) {
    for (int i = 0, n = nums.length; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int a = nums[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            int b = nums[j];
            if (target == a + b) {
                return new int[]{i, j};
            }
        }
    }
    
    throw new RuntimeException("the pair is not found");
}
```

---

Вариант решения, если можно использовать хэш-таблицы (*исправлен, если входной массив содержит дубликаты*):

```
public static int[] twoSum(final int target, int ... nums) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0, n = nums.length; i < n; i++) {
        int a = nums[i];
        int b = target - a;
        if (map.containsKey(a) && map.get(b) > -1) {
            return new int[]{map.get(b), i};
        }
        map.putIfAbsent(a, i); // запомнить меньший индекс
        map.computeIfAbsent(b, k -> -1);
        System.out.println("i=" + i + "; map=" + map);
    }
    
    throw new RuntimeException("the pair is not found");
}
```

Тесты:

```java
System.out.println("результат 1: " + Arrays.toString(twoSum(6, 2, 2, 3, 5, 1)));
System.out.println("результат 2: " + Arrays.toString(twoSum(6, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 1)));
```

```
[2, 2, 3, 5, 1]
i=0; map={2=0, 4=-1}
i=1; map={2=0, 4=-1}
i=2; map={2=0, 3=2, 4=-1}
i=3; map={1=-1, 2=0, 3=2, 4=-1, 5=3}
результат 1: [3, 4]
[2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 1]
i=0; map={2=0, 4=-1}
i=1; map={1=-1, 2=0, 4=-1, 5=1}
i=2; map={1=-1, 2=0, 4=-1, 5=1}
i=3; map={1=-1, 2=0, 3=3, 4=-1, 5=1}
результат 2: [0, 4]
```

Comment: во втором решении вот это `if (map.containsKey(a))` наверное должно быть этим `if (map.containsKey(b))`? Также не понял зачем нужно `map.computeIfAbsent(b, k -> -1);`?

Comment: в мапе ключом являются значения элементов, а значения - индексы входного массива, потому и проверяется наличие текущего числа `a`, а для числа `b` - дополнения до заданной суммы -  неизвестно, находится ли оно в мапе (существует ли индекс) - поэтому для него _при необходимости_ пишется -1.

Comment: чет сложно и по моему не оч правильно https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3RTP.png

Comment: _Нельзя использовать одно и то же число дважды._

Comment: Квадратичное решение с полным перебором устойчиво к наличию дубликатов.

Comment: Допилил и решение с мапой.

Comment: `Нельзя использовать одно и то же число дважды.` так в моем примере и не используется же?

Comment: Мапа тоже тема, просто алгоритм ваш можно упростить чутка и все заработает как надо :)

Comment: повторялась двойка

Comment: Ну во-первых она не использовалась в ответе, во вторых требование говорит о том, что нельзя один и тот же элемент коллекции с собой складывать. Требования о том, что все числа разные должны быть в массиве нет же.

Comment: А разве это не подобные утверждения: _Нельзя использовать одно и то же число дважды._ vs. _все числа разные должны быть в массиве_?  Второе, разумеется, более точное.

Comment: Не, не подобные. Утверждение «нельзя использовать число дважды» само по себе говорит об алгоритме, а не о данных. То есть у тебя уже есть массив, но вот использовать ты в нем одно и то же число не можешь дважды. К тому же сама формулировка оставляет желать лучшего - лично я понял как «не использовать число по тому же индексу дважды». В любом случае, формулировка не говорит ничего о массиве, только о том, что ты можешь/не можешь делать с данными из массива.

Comment: Выкинул все лишнее из вашего примера, получилось так https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmY0c.png

Comment: Да, но всё-таки наверное стоило использовать `putIfAbsent`, чтобы не перезаписывать индекс.

Comment: да пусть перезаписывается, с этим же нет проблем никаких. В задании сказано, что решение одно, а значит перезапись индекса ничего не изменит. Вот если бы надо было отдать все доступные решения - то тогда да, надо было бы делать мапу `map<int, hashset>`